# Entity Framework 6 Cascade Delete on One-to-Many relationship with convention disabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities in a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Staff {

    ...
    public virtual ICollection<StaffWorkingTime> WorkingTimes { get; set; }
    ...

}

public class StaffWorkingTime {

    ...
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

and disabled the default convention delete conventions:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

What I need is for the generated migration to generate a `cascadeDelete: true` for the foreign key `StaffId` in the `StaffWorkingTime` class so that when a `Staff` is deleted, all related `StaffWorkingTime` are delete as well.

Things I have tried:

Adding `[Required]` to `Staff` property in `StaffWorkingTime` class.

Using the following fluent api constructions (one at a time, not all together):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
.HasMany<StaffWorkingTime>(staff => staff.WorkingTime)
.WithRequired()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<StaffWorkingTime>()
.HasRequired<Staff>(wt => wt.Staff)
.WithMany()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

and some other variations.

I can't get the EF to generate a "cascadeDelete: true" in the migration.
It always generated the following:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Staff", t => t.StaffId)
```

Any thoughts?